# Pandas: Filter a data-frame, and assign values to top n number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,1,8,9,2], 'city':[1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,1,8,9,2]})

# The following code, creates a boolean filter,

filter = df.city==2

# Assigns True to all rows where filter is True
df.loc[filter,'selected']= True
```

What I need, is a change in the code so that it assigns True to given n number of rows.

The actual data frame has more than 3 million rows. Sometimes, I would want 
df.loc[filter,'selected']= True for only 100 rows [Actual rows could be more or less than 100].

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @ jezrael created minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Ok, so what is expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need filter by values defined in list first with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then for top 2 values use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
cities= [2,3]
df = df1[df1.city.isin(cities)].groupby('city').head(2)
print (df)
   col1  city
1     2     2
2     3     3
4     2     2
```

If need assign `True` in new column:

```
cities= [2,3]
idx = df1[df1.city.isin(cities)].groupby('city').head(2).index

df1.loc[idx, 'selected'] = True
print (df1)
    col1  city selected
0      1     1      NaN
1      2     2     True
2      3     3     True
3      4     4      NaN
4      2     2     True
5      5     5      NaN
6      6     6      NaN
7      7     7      NaN
8      1     1      NaN
9      8     8      NaN
10     9     9      NaN
11     2     2      NaN
```

Comment: @pygo - It seems you miss top values, here top2 in my sample

Comment: @pygo - not, because your solution is not top values. It is difference.

Answer (score 1):

define a list of elements to be checked and pass it to `city` columns creating a new column with `True` & `False` booleans ..

```
>>> check  
[2, 3]
>>> df['Citis'] = df.city.isin(check)
>>> df
    col1  city  Citis
0      1     1  False
1      2     2   True
2      3     3   True
3      4     4  False
4      2     2   True
5      5     5  False
6      6     6  False
7      7     7  False
8      1     1  False
9      8     8  False
10     9     9  False
11     2     2   True
```

OR

```
>>> df['Citis'] = df['city'].apply(lambda x: x in check)
>>> df
    col1  city  Citis
0      1     1  False
1      2     2   True
2      3     3   True
3      4     4  False
4      2     2   True
5      5     5  False
6      6     6  False
7      7     7  False
8      1     1  False
9      8     8  False
10     9     9  False
11     2     2   True
```

Matter of fact indeed you need to the starting (lets say 5 values to be read)

```
df['Citis'] = df.city.isin(check).head(5)

OR 

df['Citis'] = df['city'].apply(lambda x: x in check).head(5)
```

Comment: Okay there are 2 cases in my example where city == 2, but in actual datasets there are 100s cities with 1000+ rows. I need top 100,200 sometimes, only 5 rows to be assigned True

Comment: Its your prerogative  to choose what suits you !